# VB.NET LINQ Join 2 tables , then group by a column then sum

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by, sum

Datatable1

```
Name   Quantity
A       2
B       5
C       3
D       4
```

Datatable2

```
  Name   Quantity
    A       1
    B       3
    F       4
    G       4
```

Expected Result After Joining Both Datatables Grouping By Name Then Sum Quantity for each group putting the result in a new datatable

```
 Name   Quantity
    A       3
    B       8
    C       3
    D       4
    F       4
    G       4
```

is it possible to this using LINQ? note that i access a field value as `row.Field(of T)("Name")`

Comment: I'm not able to test this right now, but I think you could merge the rows, either by loading them all into one table or by converting the two collections to IEnumerables and using Concat().  After that you could GroupBy the Name and for each group, the Name would be `grp.Key` and the Quantity would be `grp.Sum(row => row.Field(of Integer)("Quantity"))`.  Then you put the result into a DataTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  I think you need Union if both the tables are the same

```
Dim query = From x in ((From p in DataTable1
                Select p).Union(From pd in DataTable2 Select pd))
                Group x By Key = x.Name Into grouping = Group
                let myProdSum = grouping.Sum(Function(x) => x.Quantity)
                Select New With {.Name = grouping.Key, .TotalQty = myProdSum}

ForEach s in query 
  Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}" , s.Name, s.TotalQty)
Next
```